# RL-ARM library's BSD sockets API

Tags: sockets, embedded, keil

Here the list of BSD sockets API within RL-ARM library

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_tn_bsd_funcs.htm

It has such note:

> ■BSD Interface functions implement a standard Berkeley Socket
>   communication interface. These APIs are not a complete implementation
>   of the BSD API.

What does this note mean?
Does it mean that some routines from list are not fully-functional? Or something other?

Answer (score 1):

It means, that there are not all socket functions present. I.e. there are no `select()`, `shutdown()`, `setsockopt()`, etc.

If you want more powerful TCP stack library with BSD sockets support, I suggest to use lwip.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it is a subset of BSD sockets API.  Those functions provided should work as per BSD.